# How to get absolute path from non-relative json-ld contentUrl?

Tags: url, json-ld, youtube-dl

I'm trying to write a new [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) extractor for a TV website. Website has json-ld support which I can use. But the url for content is not an absolute path or relative path or root-relative path. I tried using it with domain of the website but it didn't work. I appreciate any help understanding how to use this url.

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "VideoObject",
        "name": "6.Bölüm",
        "description": "6.Bölüm",
        "thumbnailUrl":"//s.kanald.com.tr/ps/kanald/70/0x0/5465f0d3cf45af1064b73084",
        "uploadDate":"2011-10-13T01:54:48.2600000+03:00",
        "duration":"PT18M32S",
        "contentUrl":"S1/HLS_VOD/d548_237/index.m3u8",
        "embedUrl":"https://www.kanald.com.tr/embed/5465f0d3cf45af1064b73086",
        "publisher": {
            "@type":"Organization",
            "name":"Kanal D",
            "logo": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "url": "https://js.kanald.com.tr/assets/dist/img/logo.v3.png",
                "width": 64,
                "height": 70
             }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

This is a json-ld snippet from the site. It is taken from [this address](https://www.kanald.com.tr/kuzeyguney/6-bolum/10397). "contentUrl" value is the part I can not figure out.

Comment: The URL would be `https://www.kanald.com.tr/kuzeyguney/6-bolum/S1/HLS_VOD/d548_237/index.m3u8`. But it’s a 404.

Comment: I know. That is why I am asking here

Comment: But what kind of answer do you expect? The question in the title is perfectly fine, and an answer could be posted how it works in JSON-LD, but that results in the 404 URL, which wouldn’t help you. -- It might be possible to ask how to get the URL from the embedded video, but that would be a different question than the one from the title.

Comment: Apparently, content is played through another domain "https://soledge21.dogannet.tv". contentUrl concatenated to this domain resulting the "https://soledge21.dogannet.tv/S1/HLS_VOD/d548_237/index.m3u8" address.